# Store the value from url params using angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-routing

```
var x = $location.search('filterBy=')[1];              
        $http({method: 'GET',url: '/asasa/sddd?websiteId='+x}).success(function(data) {
                $scope.onlinedata = data.coupons;              

            });
```

my url pattern www.asasa.com/asa/filterBy=80?couponid=121212

I am trying to store url pamars filterBy value(80) in a variable also in try to store couponid in another variable .I am using angular js 1.2.17

Comment: www.asasa.com/asa/filterBy=80?couponid=121212 ? or 
www.asasa.com/asa/?filterBy=80?couponid=121212

Comment: i can make this url like www.asasa.com/asa/?filterBy=80?couponid=121212

Comment: did you tried  to var x = $location.search('filterBy');

Comment: $location.search returning object can you console log your x like this, var x = $location.search('filterBy'); console.log(x);

Comment: yes but it pass [object%20Object]

Comment: which browser you are using ? try console.dir(x) we need to see contet of this object

Comment: problem is when i used $location.search(filterBy) url automatically add pamars filterBy in the url

Comment: In worst case you can grab the valu by using this function http://stackoverflow.com/a/901144/967859